# Weird behaviour of Kbhit and getchar

Tags: c, conio

Consider this block of C++ code.

```
    if(_kbhit()){
        //printf("Enter\n");
        c = getchar();
        int d = c;
        printf("%d", d);
        //printf("Exit \n");
    }
```

The output I get is

```
sd115d100s100
```

If I press s, d and then d, s. Weird thing is that when I pressed some character, the ascii of previously pressed character was displayed.

Now consider,

```
    if(_kbhit()){
        printf("Enter\n");
        c = getchar();
        int d = c;
        printf("%d", d);
        printf("Exit \n");
    }
```

The output I got this time is

```
aEnter
97
Exit 
dEnter
100
Exit 
dEnter
100
Exit 
aEnter
97
Exit
```

Now everything is correct the ascii code of correct character is being displayed after I pressed a character.

Why this anomaly ? How can I correct this anomaly ?

Comment: Your first shown output doesn't match the code (the code prints numbers, but not characters). Show real, complete and reproducible code.

Comment: @deviantfan Ofcourse it does not print character. The character are automatically printed on the terminal as I enter them. Do I need to show you screenshot my screen ?

Comment: Whoops, it's not getch but getchar ... I must be tired. Sorry. ... Nonetheless, a complete program (with main and everything) would be nice. Maybe you have UB. ... edit: And ... isn't getchar supposed to wait for enter...?

Comment: @deviantfan And that is completely besides the point, The question is why ascii code is different from the character entered ? If you did not read the question properly then please do so before accusing me.

Comment: Ok, if you think UB is besides the point, well ... btw., this wasn't an accusation. Undefined behaviour can very well be the answer.

Comment: @deviantfan The whole program is long.

Comment: That's why it's helpful to make a small test program with just this code, to look if it behaves similar. If not, the problem is probably somewhere else in the large program. ... (usually because UB)

Comment: @deviantfan Well I already kind of did it because rest of this program is sitting idle and this block is the only one to run. I commented other things out.

Comment: I tried (your code in a while(1) - loop, nothing else, and it worked... so... to make it clear, some if-blocks where the condition won't be fulfilled at runtime (ie. they are not executed) are plenty to invoke UB. Please try a clean small sample, it doesn't even take a minute.

Comment: @deviantfan Yes I tried still same result, but adding \n after the printf does the work.

Comment: @deviantfan I used std::cout << std::flush and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it's hard to say for sure without seeing the entire function, but I suspect the additional `printf` statements are flushing the output buffer for you, since they contain newline characters. Change

`printf("%d", d);`

to

`printf("%d\n", d);`

and see if that doesn't have the result you want.

Comment: While that's a good idea, something is strange then ... if the output buffer isn't full enough after the first s, but after the next d, it should print both numbers together, not just the first one.

Comment: See this question: [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin).

Comment: @deviantfan Consider this: `getchar()` echoes the input as its typed already, and thanks to `_kbhit()`, it won't wait for the Enter key to be pressed because `stdin` already has a character. Apparently echoing input to the screen is done by writing to stdout rather than writing to the console directly, resulting in flushing of stdout on each character entered, else the character pressed wouldn't get printed until a `\n` was sent on stdout.